# Get selected location from Google Maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to return the location selected by the user in the Google Maps Android application, but I can't seem to find information about how to achieve this task.

I created an Intent to open the GMaps Activity, but the user can't select a point on the map nor does the Activity return a point to my application when it is closed.

I'm using `startActiviyForResult`, since I'm expecting a result back from the Activity.

Answer (score 47):

You could simply use [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker) instead of implementing your own MapActivity. You will need to add Google Play Services library reference in your project though.

Just startActivityForResult with the intent provided by PlacePicker.IntentBuilder

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

Context context = getApplicationContext();
startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

And then receive the results in onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker for further details.

A bit too late to answer your question but hope this helps someone having same requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately PlacePicker activity doesn't have allow the user to search

Comment: Heads up, PlacePicker will be deprecated as of July 29, 2019. See more here https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker

Answer (score 8):

For maps API V2 you can use onMapClickListener.

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

For details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for markers dragging.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude())).draggable(true));
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    LatLng newLocation = marker.getPosition();
                    mLocation.setLatitude(newLocation.latitude);
                    mLocation.setLongitude(newLocation.longitude);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude()), 15.0f));

                }
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {}

            });
```

then return your new location.i.e mLocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with [Mapbox Android SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/). They have a good tutorial:

> [How to build a location picker for your app! | Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/android-location-picker/)

The main components needed are:

- Android ImageView for the drop pin.
- Mapbox Android SDK Marker API.
- Mapbox Android Services to do the geocoding.

[image: Location picker]